# Tor port 9051 does not listen

Tags: scrapy, port, tor

I am total newbee... did not know what webscraping meant 2 weeks ago.  After some research, I have implemented a python3 code using beautifulsoup and selenium.  Works well.  Now, given the volume of data i need to scrape, I have understood that scrapy1 can be the right tool, especially if I rotate IP addresses.  I found some bits of code which in theory should work.  However, when the RetryChangeProxyMiddleware is called, then I get the following message:

[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I therefore used this:

```
from stem.control import Controller
```

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:

```
controller.authenticate('canal007')  # provide the password here if you set one

bytes_read = controller.get_info("traffic/read")
bytes_written = controller.get_info("traffic/written")

print("My Tor relay has read %s bytes and written %s." % (bytes_read, bytes_written))
```

which returns the same message.  So I guess that I have a 'port listening porblem' on my side.  I am supposed to have admin rights on my windows machine. I believe I am not using any proxy (I am cautious here as I am no expert,...). I tried to turn on and off the Windows firewall but it does not change anything.

Tor is installed, and when I run it it works.  Save for some websites, but the one I try to scrape with scrapy is accessible with Tor.

Here is my torrc.orig.1 file:
ControlPort 9051
AUTHENTICATE "mypasswd"

I have generated a hashkey with tor.exe and used it in the following middleware which i call with scrapy:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if random.choice(range(1,100)) <= 80:
            logging.log(logging.INFO, 'Changing proxy')
            tn = telnetlib.Telnet('127.0.0.1', 9051)
            tn.read_until("Escape character is '^]'.", 2)
            tn.write('AUTHENTICATE "<hashkey>"\r\n')
            tn.read_until("250 OK", 2)
            tn.write("signal NEWNYM\r\n")
            tn.read_until("250 OK", 2)
            tn.write("quit\r\n")
            tn.close()
            logging.log(logging.INFO, '>>>> Proxy changed. Sleep Time')
            time.sleep(10)
```

If I discard this middleware, then I can scrape.  But I dont have rotating IP addresses,... so I will sooner or later be rejected from the server I want to scrape.

If anyone can help in a quite didactic way this would be fantastic.

Thanks to the community!!

Comment: If you run `netstat -anp` on Windows does it show Tor listening on 9051?

Comment: did you ever figure out what the problem was?